# How to use bit shift in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to perform some bit-shifting operations to convert `0110 0100 0000` to `1100 1000` in VBA code. This example is a decimal value of 200.

I have tried the following code but it seems like the `>>` is not working. Also, how do I set the data type to zero to clear all bits?

If `wordmsg` is a 32-bit word, How can I set bit 30 and bit 31 equal to 1?

```
Sub test()
    'Declaring variables
    Dim simvalue As Integer, wordmsg As Integer, test As Integer, resolution As Integer

    simvalue= 200
    resolution = 0.0625

    wordmsg = simvalue / resolution
    test = wordmsg >> 3
End sub
```

Comment: What code have you tried already?

Comment: @braX, I will include the code I have tried above. Thanks

Comment: @braX, please see new edit

Comment: You can go `test = wordmsg / 8`.

Comment: don't forget to declare `resolution` variable.

Comment: @braX, what if this is a 32-bit word and I want to set bit 30 and 31 equal to 1. Do you know how I can do that? Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no bit shift operator in VBA. You can, generally speaking, multiply, divide, AND and OR your way around.

Excel exposes the `Bitand`, `Bitlshift`, `Bitor`, `Bitrshift` and `Bitxor` functions to VBA through Application.WorksheetFunction.

Example: `test = Application.WorksheetFunction.Bitrshift(wordmsg, 3)`.

To manipulate 32-bit words in VBA, you can't use the `Long` type, because its most significant bit (MSB, bit 31) holds the sign (negative when set). Attempting to set bit 31 with e.g. `myLong = 2 ^ 31` will result in an overflow. You can use the `Double` type as a stand-in dword, and the `Application.WorksheetFunction.Bit[...]` functions will work with up to 48 bits (2^48 - 1; decimal 281474976710655).

```
Sub BitRightShiftTest()
    Dim d As Double
    
    d = (2 ^ 31) + (2 ^ 30) + (200 / 0.0625)
    Debug.Print d
    
    d = Application.WorksheetFunction.Bitrshift(d, 3)
    Debug.Print d
End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome, this helps to clarify some confusion I had. Thank you!

Comment: what does Debug.Print do?

Comment: It sends output to the Immediate Window, which you can show by pressing Ctrl+G from the Visual Basic Editor. As the name implies, it's for debugging purposes, and shouldn't be left in the code.

Comment: I am not sure why `test = Application.WorksheetFunction.Bitrshift(wordmsg, 3)`  did not work. It gives an error saying "Unable to get the Bitrshift property of the Worksheet Function Class"

Comment: I am using Excel 2016

Comment: You've now declared wordmsg as a Double, right? Make sure it contains a whole number (no decimals).

Comment: Yup, I did. I am not sure why excel vba is not taking that function

Comment: Does the `Test` sub in my answer work on your machine? If it does, show us _your_ code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157412/discussion-between-excelosaurus-and-jesus).

Answer (score 1):

Try BITRSHIFT function. http://www.excelfunctions.net/excel-bitrshift-function.html. If not available, use multiplication instead.

Comment: Great, thank you.  I was able to use the BITRSHIFT function and it worked.

Comment: what if wordmsg is a 32-bit word and I want to set bit 30 and 31 equal to 1. Do you know how I can do that? Thank

Comment: See my answer to this.